# Windows 8 boot failure after install of Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

I am new to Ubuntu and all of Linux. I installed Lubuntu 17.04 on my laptop that already had Windows 8 installed, to have a dual boot system. (Due to windows 8 being preinstalled, I don't have an install disc). I installed Ubuntu using a flash drive and I set my computer to legacy mode in the UEFI utility. This was the only way I could get it to work.

I get to the grub menu and I can boot Ubuntu, but can not boot Windows 8. When I try I am greeted with a black screen for a moment and the a screen that tells me there was a boot error. Below are the directions for how to fix it with a disc. it says:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD  

  Status: 0xc000000e  

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

Due to my pc being in legacy mode, boot repair does not seem to work, or atleast I havn't been able to get it to work. I have also tried to make what I think was a custom boot option for windows from an answer from a question similar to mine. I will be needing this computer for school and need to get this fixed soon. Is there a way that I can do it on my own, do I have to take it into an expert, or have i messed it up beyond all repair and now need a new copy of windows, ect?

Comment: No, "Legacy" certanly not the only way and that is the reason why Windows doesn't boot. Do not use Boot Repair or any hack now. You've already made a mistake, don't make it worse. Either live with it by changing modes at UEFI or install Ubuntu properly in UEFI mode: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: You should be able to run Ubuntu installer in live mode UEFI & add Boot-Repair. Then post link to summary report. Sometimes you can just reinstall all of grub in UEFI mode. And you should with UEFI be always able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12 check manual. And you need to make a Windows repair flash drive.

Comment: There is an easy way to get into windows if Ubuntu was installed in legacy. All you have do do is on startup press the key that brings you into the boot manager for your computer,mine was f12. Then choose the windows efi option, and it should then run windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very easy way to run windows(that is installed in efi) if ubuntu was installed in legacy. Shut down the computer and when starting up press the key that brings you into boot manager,mine was f12. From the boot manager screen choose the windows efi option, and it should load windows. This may not be the best fix, but it allows you to get into windows. This worked for me on my lenovo flex 3. Hopefully this helps anyone else who installed ubuntu in legacy mode.